# Micronaut - Creating, Getting and Destroying ApplicationContext beans

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client

I have a need to dynamically create and destroy `HttpClient` objects, to correspond with clients registering/deregistering themselves with my Micronaut application. As part of this I want to add them as beans to the application context so that they automatically use the custom `HttpFilter`s also in the project.

I thought it would be fairly simple to manage these beans using the `ApplicationContext` bean methods with a name `Qualifier` to keep track of them, but the way these APIs seem to behave is baffling to me:

1. `applicationContext.createBean(HttpClient.class, Qualifiers.byName("myLabel"), myUrl)` fails with:

```
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type 
[io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean 
requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the 
bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is 
enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as 
an annotation processor).
```

**Why does it matter if the bean exists?  I'm trying to create it!**

2. `applicationContext.findBean(HttpClient.class)` fails with:

```
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient]

Message: Missing bean argument [LoadBalancer loadBalancer] for type: io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient. Required arguments: LoadBalancer loadBalancer,HttpClientConfiguration configuration,String contextPath,HttpClientFilterResolver filterResolver
```

**Why is it trying to create it? I just want to find it!**

(**NOTE**. `applicationContext.getBean(HttpClient.class, Qualifiers.byName("myLabel"))` may work here, but because I haven't been able to resolve point one I haven't been able to verify this)

3. `applicationContext.destroyBean(HttpClient.class)` doesn't allow a `Qualifier` to be specified in the method which means I can't use it to remove the bean from the context.  It also return null after bean creation without a qualifier (`applicationContext.createBean(HttpClient.class, myUrl)`) which suggests it can't find the created bean anyway...

**I assume I'm using the wrong API here, but what is the correct one?**

All-in-all I'm thoroughly confused - any help on the proper use of these APIs would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpClient` is the interface intended to define a an http-client but not a bean (note that the default ~ `DefaultHttpClient` ~ implementation afforded by *Micronaut* is not a bean). Hence any calls to the mentioned `ApplicationContext` context lookup or instantiation methods will all result in errors:

- `ApplicationContext#createBean`
- `ApplicationContext#findBean`
- `ApplicationContext#getBean`
- ... // other instantiation methods

Note this is intentionally made by design since the `HttpClient` API is intended to be injected automatically and operating through AOP advice.

You can either inject a raw (with default methods) `HttpClient`:

```
@Singleton
public class MyBeanIml implements MyBean {

  @Client
  HttpClient client;

  // ...
}
```

Or for custom methods, *generated implementation*, you can use the `HttpClient` declarative implementation:

```
@Client("endpoint-uri")
public interface MyHttpClient {

  @Get
  String query();

  // ...
}
```

Without specifying your exact requirements for creating custom (dynamic by the way is too *vague* in this context) `HttpClient`s, the way you can go with is to have a custom `@Prototype`d bean wrapping a *injected* `HttpClient` that can be instantiated with your custom parameters and where you delegate your methods to the wrapped `HttpClient` or implement your custom methods:

```
@Prototype
public class CustomHttpClientImpl implements CustomHttpClientImpl.CustomHttpClient {

    @Inject
    @Client
    private final HttpClient httpClient;

    private final String endpoint;

    public CustomHttpClientImpl(@Parameter String endpoint, HttpClient httpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

        @Override
    public String query() {
        return this.httpClient.toBlocking()
                .exchange(HttpRequest.GET(URI.create(this.endpoint)), String.class)
                .body();
    }
    
    // delegate to the `httpClient` bean or implement your custom API querying methods

    public interface CustomHttpClient {

        String query();
    }
}
```

Then you can create your `Prototype`d bean instances using the `ApplicationContext`:

```
applicationContext.createBean(CustomHttpClient.class, "som-uri-for-custom-client");
```